# Just need a comma separated list from PHP/MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I can't figure out why this is so difficult.
I have a SQL query that results in a column of numeric results, i.e.:

```
23
45
67
54
34
78
56
```

Using a PHP/MySQL query, I want to simply generate a comma separated list of these values that can be displayed or used elsewhere.  This is the code I am using

```
 <?php


global $wpdb;

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT FK_T_L_INCENTIVES_ID FROM lighting_incentives.WAYPOINT_USER_PICKED WHERE WP_RECOMMENDED = 1 AND FK_USER_ID = 31
SQL;

if (!$sql) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$resultset = array();
$rebates = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
foreach($rebates as $data) {
    $resultset[] = $data;
}
$comma_separated = implode(",", $resultset);

print $comma_separated;
?>
```

For some reason I keep getting the error

```
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: is $rebates returning an error?

Comment: Just testing the string truthiness with `if (!$sql)` won't tell you about the validity of the query; which is run after that.

Comment: I guess you are using wordpress if so then `$wpdb` is an object of wpdb's class and you don't need to call `mysql_fetch_array()` just loop over `$rebates`

Comment: By default, `get_results()` returns "a numerically indexed array of row objects." http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

Comment: Thank you for your help, can you explain further how I can loop over `$rebates` without using `mysql_fetch_array()`?

Comment: @MattShirk what sql query are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be done in SQL if you would like... all you need to do is on the column that returns the numbers do this `GROUP_CONCAT(column_name)` and it'll put all in one row with it comma separated

removes the need to write multiple lines of php code

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$resultset=array();
$rebates = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($rebates,MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $resultset[] = $data;
}
```

to

```
$resultset = array();
$rebates = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
foreach($rebates as $data) {
    $resultset[] = $data;
}
```

[More info on how to use get_results()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Using_the_.24wpdb_Object)

Comment: Thank you for your help! After replacing the code you suggested, I now get this error

`Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: Added a second argument to get you an array

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have updated the current version of my code above.  Now when the page loads I get

 `Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array `

Do you have any additional insight into how I can change each of these "array" strings to the number I desire?

Comment: @MattShirk that is the correct response, you are just printing the whole array.. try changing your print to something like `print_r ($comma_separated);` if you want to see the info in the array

Comment: @JohnRuddell 
Thanks for your help, however after adding
`print_r ($comma_separated);  `
I still receive the same response
`Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,  etc`

Comment: probably because its making an array of arrays.. did you try my answer? might be a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$resultset = array();
$rebates = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
foreach($rebates as $data) {
$resultset[] = (array) $data;
}

$comma_separated = implode(",", $resultset);

echo  $comma_separated;
```

Answer (score 0):

$wpdb does not return a MySQL, please try:

```
$table_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT id FROM table" );
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

@JohnRuddell @Machavity

Thanks for your help.  Here is code that finally worked.

```
<?php


global $wpdb;
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT FK_T_L_INCENTIVES_ID FROM lighting_incentives.WAYPOINT_USER_PICKED WHERE WP_RECOMMENDED = 1 AND FK_USER_ID = $user_ID
SQL;

if (!$sql) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$resultset = array();
$rebates = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
foreach($rebates as $data) {
     echo $data['FK_T_L_INCENTIVES_ID']. ",";
}

?>
```